# C# structure recommendation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

As a C# begiginer, I'm coding an UWP app. The app is currently working exactly like expected but I wonder if there is a better approch for the fact that my images arrays are declared
as Global for the Class. I searched for an alternative for several hours but didn't find an example that match my need.

Below is a reprentation of my code:

```
namespace myUWPapp
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        string[] imgImagesSourceFileName = { "images1.png", "image2.png", "image3.png", "image4.png", "image5.png" };
        string[] btnImagesSourceFileName = { "images6.png", "image7.png", "image8.png", "image9.png", "image10" };

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            ...
            ...
        }
        private string GetImageFileName(string[] array, int index)
        {
            string image = array[index];

            return image;
        }
        private void ReverseArray(string[] array)
        {
            Array.Reverse(array);
        }
        private void MethodeUsingGetImagesSourceFileName()
        {
            ...         
            string image = GetImageFileName(myArray, myIndex);
            ...         
        }
        private void MethodeUsingReverseArray()
        {
            ...
            ...
            ReversesArray(myImagesArray);
        }
    }
}
```

Looking forward for alternative but don't forget that I'm a relatively new at coding.

Comment: what are you looking for you application to do?

Comment: For a first app I'm learning by creating a board game.

Comment: You are free to declare a new class named ‘MyImages’ and move the image arrays from MainPage to the new class. Just expose them thru public properties so the MainPage can use them.

Comment: I don' have enough knowledge to do that since the image Class would only be a structure without content.Then from the main I would need to call a constructor for each image. So I would still need to have the images names in the main.

Comment: No i would create the class suggested by @kennyzx and create a method that returns an image so that way all image based logic(except display logic) is contained within the created class

Comment: I'm not really sure how you reason `GetImageFilenameFromArray(myArray,1)` is clearer that just writing `myArray[1]` but I did want to point out that StackOverflow isn't for peer review of working code, it's for help with broken code. This question probably belongs on codereview.stackexhange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I believe it is a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com (but that site isn't presented in the offtopic/migration option list [on a mobile])

Comment: @CaiusJard as this code isn't complete (it's only "a representation of [..] code"), it's off-topic on CR. Please see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: @zeta but he says his app is complete and working correctly. If he's posting a pseudocode fragment to garner opinion on possible ways then that might be softwareengineering.se but I'm still pretty sure this Q isn't a fit for SO

Comment: @CaiusJard Have a closer look at the code. Code Review only accepts _complete_ and _working_ code, not `...` cuts or placeholders. This is all explained in the link above, though.

Comment: @zeta I don't think what codereviews rules are affect whether this question is a good fit for SO or not; the OP says that the program is complete and works so this question could easily be ported to codereview and made to fit its rules by including the missing portions. This question is about code review, not problem resolution; it doesn't fit SO's purpose well.

Comment: @CaiusJard I never said that it's on-topic on SO, only that a migration in its current state is not appropriate :). It's certainly off-topic here and should get closed as primary opinion. One can still point out in the comments that another site *might* be appropriate if the question is heavily edited. However, as mentioned in the link above, you should point out why it's off-topic *here*, not why it *might be* on-topic somewhere else. Re migration list: short fun fact: [Code Review will never be on the migration list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266749/1139697).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are your images located?  In a folder in your project?  If so, you can just do something like this to get all the image file names:

```
// Get the path to the app's Assets folder.
string root = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path;
string path = root + @"\Assets";  // where your image files are located

// Get the folder object that corresponds to this absolute path in the file system.
StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(path);

IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> items = await folder.GetFilesAsync();

List<string> listOfNames = items.Select(x=>x.Name).ToList();
//or you can leave it as IEnumerable... or you can convert ToArray()
```

Comment: Fyi, you should just keep a reference to the `StorageFile` instead of the names... You can use the Select statement to get the names for display purposes in a getter.

Answer (score 1):

I checked your code, I think `MethodeUsingGetImagesSourceFileName` and `MethodeUsingReverseArray` are inflexible. If you just want to process string array, you could create `ListExtension` with `List<string>` for your image array.

```
public static class ListExtension
{
    public static void InitializeImageArray(this List<string> items, int start,int end)
    {
        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
        {
            items.Add($"images{i}.png");
        }
    }
    public static string GetImageFileNameWithIndex(this List<string> items, int index)
    {
        return items[index];
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
private List<string> _imgImageitems = new List<string>();
private List<string> _btnImageitems = new List<string>();

private void InitializeImages()
{
    _imgImageitems.InitializeImageArray(1, 5);
    _btnImageitems.InitializeImageArray(6, 10);
}
```

**Get image file name with index**

```
string image = _imgImageitems.GetImageFileNameWithIndex(1);
```

**Reverse list**

```
_imgImageitems.Reverse();
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this and let you know. It seems what I was looking for.